# How do I post back to an MVC controller action via Javascript

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I have a aspx page that is defined as:

```
    <%Using Html.BeginForm("SaveNotifications", "Notifications", FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "NotificationForm"})%>
    ...
                    <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="submit" id="SaveNotifications" name="SaveNotifications" value="Save" class="t-button" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </fieldset> 
    <%End Using %>
```

I want to change this so that my input button fires a javascript function so that I can do some complex validation of the form and THEN post to the controller.

I changed my submit button to:

```
    <input type="submit" id="SaveNotifications" name="SaveNotifications" value="Save" class="t-button" onclick="onSave(); return false;" />
```

The onSave() method would fire but not post back to the controller.

The controller is defined as:

```
    <HttpPost()> _
    <MultiButton(MatchFormKey:="SaveNotifications", MatchFormValue:="Save")> _
    Function SaveNotifications(ByVal NotificationForm As FormCollection) As ActionResult
    ...
    End Function
```

How do I change this so that the javascript fires, runs my validation and then hits this controller action?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your submit button to

`<input type="submit" id="SaveNotifications" name="SaveNotifications" value="Save" class="t-button" onclick="return onSave();" />`

Then in the javascript onSave() function, return true or false depending on the validation.

```
function onSave()
{
    var isValid = true;
    // ... do your validation ...

    // ie:
    // if (field1.value.length == 0)
    //     isValid = false;


    // returning true will post the form.  False will halt it.
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: How will the javascript fire if the submit button has no onclick event pointing to onSave()?

Comment: Ok got it, just don't "return false;"

Comment: Exactly - edited my answer for a bit more clarity.  Well, you still return true or false from the onClick, but that's evaluated in the onSave function.